# div elements overlapping instead of aligning vertically

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want a div element's top margin to match with the bottom of another, how can I do this?

Can I do it without using tables?

```
<div style="text-align:left; position:absolute; left:12%;">
<input type="checkbox" name="acceptance" value="I have read and agree with the terms and conditions.">
<label style="text-align:left; color:yellowgreen ;font-size:27px ;font-family:cursive;font-style:italic;">I have read and agree with the terms and conditions</label>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center; width = 100%;">
<a href="i-hm-p.html";><img border="0"  src="images/imappyenter.png" width="100px"></a>
</div>
```

Please ignore my bad formatting, I'm editing someone else's code as well as learning CSS.

What I want to do is I want to place a checkbox at 12% of total width in a line, and a short explanation for it immediately after. I've placed both in one div element.

In another div element, I've placed a link wrapped in an image, which I want to align centrally while not being in the same line as the checkbox and its visible explanation.

How can I do this?

Comment: add css and html or fiddle to explain yourself

Comment: You must be doing something to cause the `div`s to overlap in the first place. Because they don't just do that. Also, you should provide code so we can see where the problem is.

Comment: have you tried adding a z-index? it allows an element with greater stack order to be in front of an element with a lower stack order. Maybe am wrong? Also please show your code

Comment: You should only be using tables for tabular data, you should also be aware of [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)

Comment: Look at this, 2 `div`'s. By default they will not overlap. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eM5j2/)

Comment: added code, please help...

Comment: @hrishirc You are using `position:absolute;`. This will allow other elements under it (I would reccomend looking up what it does). How do you want it to look on the page? Removing that will fix them being on the same line. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eM5j2/1/)

Comment: @hrishirc I am guessing you would like it like this. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eM5j2/2/) if you would like me to explain it I will create an answer.

Comment: Thanks Ruddy, I do know that, but using relative instead, shifts the checkbox slightly more right to a 'form-table' (text at 12% width, form in a cell right horizontally adjacent) I've placed above it. While logically should not do so, I've no clue why it happens (e.g. if it's at 12% width, the checkbox shifts to something very small, say 0.1% to the right, but which is discernible. Is there anyway to stop that from happening?

Comment: @hrishirc Not sure what you what it to do. Did you take a look at my second edit? Surely that's what your after. Show me all the code.

Comment: ohk, you've solved something I'd forgotten, usage of position:absolute, the thing is position:relative shifts the 'left' to something slightly more than left:12%, say left:12.01%, something visible. If you see the code output in some major browser, you'll see what I'm talking about. I've a table containing rows of forms above it all starting at 12% width positioned _relatively_. And the difference clearly shows. It's probably an implementation issue for CSS. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: Sorry, not 0.01%, I just checked, almost 2% difference. There's an implementation problem involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `position:absolute` to `position:relative`

Comment: That will then cause a scroll bar. Don't think they would want that.

Comment: What about adding `width:88%`?